# Prisma typescript type error when creating record

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, prisma, remix.run

I 'm using prisma with MySql.
When I try to create a new record (School) I get a type error in console.
I'm using a framework called Remix.run too, but it shouldn't be the problem.

I've tried using mongoDB too, but i got the same type error.

#### Error

```
251 console.log(info);
252 });
253 let data = {school_code: key, otp: code};
→ 254 await db.schools.create({
    data: {
        school_code: 'ISP0TMORECNJS9TB',
        ~~~~~~~~~~~
        otp: 'EMI5DU'
    }
})

Unknown arg `school_code` in data.school_code
for type schoolsCreateInput.Available args:

    type schoolsCreateInput {
        id ? : String
        v ? : Int | Null
        otp: String
    }
```

#### Prisma schema

```
datasource db {
    provider = "mysql"
    url = "mysql://root@localhost:3306/myeducatio"
}

model schools {
    otp String @db.Text
    school_code String @id
}
```

## Code

#### Method 1

```
let data: any = {
    school_code: key,
    otp: code
};

await db.schools.create({
    data,
});
```

#### Method 2

```
await db.schools.create({
    data: {
        school_code: key,
        otp: code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I had installed prisma outside my project folder.
I just deleted it and reinstalled it.